# How to set bean property value from other bean property value using struts1

Tags: java, struts

For example I have bean `Academicboardform` with Long property boardid:And second bean `GradeBoardConfigureForm` has also some properties with Academicboardform class reference like this.

```
public class GradeBoardConfigureForm extends ActionForm {

    private Academicboardform selectboard;
////setter/getters.
}
```

In My Jsp i am using like this but it is not going to the action class.

```
 <html:select  name="GradeBoardConfigureForm" property="selectboard.boardid">
      <html:option value="0">Select Board List</html:option>
      <html:optionsCollection  name="GradeBoardConfigureForm" property="boardlist" label="boardname" value="boardid"/>
 </html:select>
```

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is.

Comment: What does "it is not going to the action class" actually mean? Also can you post the rendered HTML (from the source of the page in your browser) for that select element?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use nested form beans. The reason is the only one action form is instantiated by Struts when you submit a form.

The action form (or form bean) that is configured to the action will be created and populated by Struts.

If you want to pass the value upon a submission you should add a hidden field to the form and set the value using a current action form or javascript in the `onClick` event of the `<html:submit>` button.